# R ggplot2 scatterplot: adding color for the level of deviation from (regression) geom_smooth line

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a scatterplot (two continuous variables) with ggplot2 that has a regression line. My small dataset (of yearly averages) has most data points on the regression line or close to it and some observations are placed a bit more far away. Would it be possible to color code the observations on the scatterplot based on their distance from the regression line?

This far I manually created the color value groups for the variables myself but this looks a bit too biased. I would like to have something automatic, if possible.

```
ggplot(data_mean, aes(x= policy1, y= policy2 ))+
  geom_point(aes(colour = group), size=4) +geom_text_repel(aes(label=iso),hjust=0, vjust=0) + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, size=0.1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Country Categories", # or name = element_blank()
 values=colors) +
theme(legend.position="bottom",
       legend.title=element_blank())
```

Would it be possible to color code the observations on the scatterplot based on their distance from the regression line? Thank you!

Comment: Please share your data as well, or a toy data set with the same characteristics, so it's possible to test appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tough to define which are outliers, and it really depends on the data you have. You can try something like below, where I calculate the residuals from the linear regression, and define those that are outside 2 * sd (residuals) to be outliers.

First something that looks like your data, with some error introduced to policy2

```
set.seed(888)
data_mean=data.frame(policy1=1:20,policy2=1:20 + rnbinom(20,mu=2,size=2))
data_mean$residuals = abs(lm(policy2~policy1,data=data_mean)$residuals)
# here we define the outliers to be those more than 2 standard error of residuals
data_mean$group = data_mean$residuals > 2*sd(data_mean$residuals)
data_mean$iso = letters[1:20]
```

Then we plot:

```
ggplot(data_mean, aes(x= policy1, y= policy2))+
geom_point(aes(colour = group), size=4) +
geom_text_repel(aes(label=iso),hjust=0, vjust=0) + 
geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, size=0.1) +
theme(legend.position="bottom",
       legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

One alternative is actually to using a continuous scale:

```
ggplot(data_mean, aes(x= policy1, y= policy2))+
  geom_point(aes(colour = residuals), size=4) +
geom_text_repel(aes(label=iso),hjust=0, vjust=0) + 
geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, size=0.1) +
theme(legend.position="bottom",
       legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_color_viridis()
```

[image]

Again, will be great if you share some bits of the data, and also elaborate on how you want to color the points based on the residuals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me this before I could upload data, that is great. The continuous scale was the exactly the one that I was looking for.

Comment: can we get only the outliers which above  2*sd only not all points labelled...?